# html multiple select inside div stretching entire page

Tags: html, css

I have a buch of multiple select boxes and I wanted to line them up in a line across the page. I thought I could do this with the help of divs, but for some reason I am running into trouble. Each select is being stretched across the entire width of the page even though I specified in the css that I didn't want that. Why is this happening?
Also, I am giving each select a title by just putting text on top of it. Is there a better way to make a title?

HTML

```
<div class='bold'>
            <div id="parameters">
                <div class="section">Program<br> <select multiple="multiple" name="program">
                            <option value="SGS">SGS</option>
                        </select>
                </div>      
                <div class="section">School <br><select multiple="multiple" name="school">
                            <option value="FLH">FLH</option>
                            <option value="MID">MID</option>
                            <option value="SUN">SUN</option>
                            <option value="MNC">MNC</option>
                        </select>
                </div>      
                <div class="section">Term <br><select multiple="multiple" name="term">
                            <option value="Fall 2011">Fall 2011</option>
                            <option value="Late Fall 2011">Late Fall 2011</option>
                        </select>
                </div>      
                <div class="section">Extension<br> <select multiple="multiple" name="ext">
                            <option>Something...</option>
                        </select>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#parameters{width:100%
        height:150px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:2px;
        border-color:grey;} 
.section{width:50px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are block elements so will stack on top of each other by default. If you want them to sit next to each other you will need to [float](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) them.

```
.section{
     float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGmTL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
.section {
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

This is an alternative to float to a degree. It may suit your needs better, but it's difficult to say. `display: inline-block` comes with [rendering drawbacks](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/), as does float of course.

I prefer it sometimes - A lot of people jump at float like it's the only choice, but it can be a real pain too.

[JSFiddle sample using display rather than float](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/CGmTL/2/)

As you can see, it preserves your border without using a clearfix, whereas float breaks the border.

edit: If you choose to use float, a good method of making the border wrap around the contained elements is to add `overflow: auto` to `#parameters`, as shown in the fiddle below:

[Float fiddle with clearfix](http://jsfiddle.net/echopony/L6CFh/)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your html code a bit in order to use labels in the "tittle" of each select tag.

You can view here: http://jsfiddle.net/SmRzL/4/

Answer (score 0):

In regards to how to align, your elements you need to float each section:

```
.section{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

In regards, to adding a title to each section personally I would do something along the lines of this:

```
<span class="title">Term </span> 

.title {
    display:block;
    font: bold 1em "Arial Narrow", "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial;
}
```

See this fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/8rQXD/